# Permitted to detach grape juice bottle from plastic thing on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Kedem grape juice sometimes comes in a pack of 2 large bottles that are connected by a plastic thing.  Would it be permitted on Shabbos to detach one bottle from the plastic thing?   Here is a picture.  [image]

Comment: What are your concerns? Are you looking for a personal and binding psak halacha or is this grounded in an analysis of halachic methodology?

Comment: Why should it be forbidden? the plastic just pulls loose.